# Android IllegalStateException when recording audio on some devices

Tags: java, android

I want my program to record audio for 10 seconds and then stop and store my record in file storage, everything works fine on my Nexus 4 and Galaxy S 5, but when i test it in Galaxy S3 it crushes and raise error

`10-02 02:13:44.942    1279-1279/com.taptester.tappapp E/AudioCaptureDemo﹕ prepare() failed
10-02 02:13:44.942    1279-1279/com.taptester.tappapp E/MediaRecorder﹕ start called in an invalid state: 4
10-02 02:13:44.942    1279-1279/com.taptester.tappapp D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-02 02:13:44.942    1279-1279/com.taptester.tappapp W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a12ba8)
10-02 02:13:44.952    1279-1279/com.taptester.tappapp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.taptester.tappapp, PID: 1279
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
            at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
            at com.taptester.tappapp.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:203)
            at com.taptester.tappapp.MainActivity.access$300(MainActivity.java:62)
            at com.taptester.tappapp.MainActivity$6.onFinish(MainActivity.java:825)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

First i thought the error is in the file name, I'm declaring it like this:

```
public MainActivity() {
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator
            + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + File.separator + "MyMemo.3gp";
    //Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    //mFileName += "/MyMemo.3gp";
}
```

Then i make a record like this:

```
private void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }


}
```

Then i call the "StartRecording" method like this:

```
else if(command.equals("2")) {

                    startRecording();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start recording...",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    CountDownTimer start = new CountDownTimer(timer, 1000) {

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long l) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording!!!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            stopRecording();

                        }
                    }.start();
```

Comment: @MikeM. No problem isn't there, 'cause i've tried with it and without it, problem is not going away.

Comment: @MikeM. i'm sure, 'cause i've tried with the commented methods, and it stores in root folder.

Comment: @MikeM. but DCIM is for camera. I'm recording with microphone, without camera usage.

Comment: @MikeM. yes, DCIM folder is there. I guess the problem is in that it doesn't let to create the file, or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

1. you are not supposed to call mRecorder.start(); when mRecorder.prepare(); fails.

this is what caused the Illegal State Exception to be thrown.

2. Not all devices support all the encoding formats.
   try changing these mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   and  mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

change the format and Encoder to a file format and encoding format your s3 device supports.

for a start, change your encoding setting to default settings as follows and try if it works.
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);

Comment: Hm, i thought THREE_GP and AMR_NB are standard for all devices, but okay i'll try. Updated code.